# Problem with Python Code and the Functions in it

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Problem, I have to solve a task in Python and I dont know how to do it. The task is to define a function number_of_vowels, where the output should be the Number of vowels in a Word. With this function I have to write anotherone, many_vowels thats working with a list an a Number and where the number says how many vowels have to be at least in a word to be appended to the result list and then I have to append this Word. Thanks to everybody helping me ;D.

here is the code:

```
Wort = "parameter"


def number_of_vowels(Word):
    result = 0
    counter0 = 0
    while result < 20:
        if Word[counter0] == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
            result = result + 1
            counter0 = counter0 + 1
        else:
            counter0 = counter0 + 1
        return result 


Words = []
counter1 = 0


def many_vowels(List , number):
    if number_of_vowels(List[counter1]) < number:
        counter1 + 1
    else:
        Words.append(List[counter1])
        counter1 + 1
    return Words
```

This code just gives me the answer to the letter a and not to the other vowels. For

```
print(number_of_vowels(Wort))
```

the output is: 1
but there are 4 vowels in this word
it also says: line 21, in many_vowels
IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call a function with wrong brackets. Function call should use round ones.

Try changing `number_of_vowels[List[counter1]]` with `number_of_vowels(List[counter1])`

Answer (score 0):

This code contains some errors:

1. Calling for function should be using round brackets: `number_of_vowels(List[counter1])` instead of `number_of_vowels[List[counter1]]`
2. doing `result + 1` won't change value of the variable result, since you did not put the calculation result in the variable. use `result = result + 1` (same for counters)
3. in `number_of_vowels` function, you want to scan the whole word? cause you did not use any loop, so it currently looking only at the first letter. Secondly, you put the compression in result and then add 1 to it. I'm not really sure why

edit:

```py
Word = "parameter"


def number_of_vowels(Word):
    result = 0
    counter0 = 0
    for index, letter in enumerate(Word):
        if letter == 'a' or letter == 'e' or letter == 'i' or letter == 'o' or letter == 'u':
            result = result + 1
    return result 


Words = []
counter1 = 0


def many_vowels(List_name , number):
    for index, item in enumerate (List_name):
    if number_of_vowels(item) >= number:
        Words.append(item)
    return Words
```

Comment: I have the counter to check all the letters in the word, so if one letter is checked, the counter goes up and the next letter is checked. I dont know if you can do this another way.

Comment: Thanks for youre comment these informations were very helpful but now my Programs output is only a empty list so what schould I do?

Comment: when you call to the function, It executes once. At no point at your code you call to the function more then once - it scans only the first letter. There is no part in which "next letter is checked"

Comment: So I have to add something like 'while' but I dont know how can I say that he must do it for the whole word

Comment: ```for index,item in enumerate (Word): ``` now item will be the letter and index the index in the list. it's a way to iterate a list (which I assume word is?)

Comment: There is still no result it works but the outcomming is [] a empty list

Comment: @Ace I edited my post, adding code. Not really sure what counter0 and counter1 are doing in your code, since you increment them in all cases and not returning them. My function iterate through the list, and if the letter is a vowel it increase result, and return results in the end. I think now ```numer_of_vowels``` will work fine